Why is 「手伝いにきてください」 OK, but not 「手伝ってきてください」?
In the「新完全マスター」series JLPT N4 文法 book, pg. 54, there is this question:
来週、ちょっと 私の 仕事を _________ 来て くれませんか。
(1) 手伝って, (2) 手伝いに, (3) 手伝うので, (4) 手伝うように
The answer is (2) which makes sense, but I don't see why (1) can't also be correct.  It's common in Japanese to use ~て+いく/くる to give a sense of "directionality" to an action, so why couldn't 手伝ってくる --> 手伝ってきてください also be acceptable?
Edit: It's possible that the question writing 来て in kanji is the key, since 手伝ってきて typically wouldn't use kanji.  But this seems especially nitpicky for a JLPT question - still seeking a definitive clarification.

Maybe spelling of 来て with kanji is a hint that it is not part of -te + くる construction here, where 来る is auxiliary verb and auxiliary verbs are usually written exclusively in hiragana.

@Arfrever I thought the same thing, but still unsure - added an edit to the question.

While masu-stem + に and the te-form (this derives from masu-stem + a particle て, with a sound change; so it's really just about the choice of particle) are both used to connect a modifier to a verb, they make two fundamentally different kinds of connections.
Dogen has an old video illustrating the difference in a more comedic context:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2vVPpbEdH0&t=41
In the given example: 「手伝いにくる」(ignoring the final conjugation) is "come (and) help", whereas 「手伝ってくる」could be understood as either "help and (then) come" or "come helpfully" - neither of which makes nearly as much sense.

It's common in Japanese to use ~て+いく/くる to give a sense of "directionality" to an action, so why couldn't 手伝ってくる --> 手伝ってきてください also be acceptable?

This is one of those times where it can be understood perfectly well in English terms. When you "come help" someone, you aren't helping towards that person - your aid isn't a form of motion, so it doesn't have direction. Rather, you are moving towards that person for the purpose of being more helpful. This に connotes purpose.

It's possible that the question writing 来て in kanji is the key, since 手伝ってきて typically wouldn't use kanji. But this seems especially nitpicky for a JLPT question

I don't think this is intended as nitpicking; I think it's just making a natural style choice that happens to offer an additional contextual clue. Indeed, 〜きて as a conjugation normally not use kanji (and one would learn this readily through experience, because it's the same story for other modals and auxiliaries: we almost never see [為]{す}る after a suru-verb, or 〜[過]{す}ぎる etc. even though we would see 過ぎる as a verb by itself "to exceed"). But also, 〜に来て commonly would - because not only are there other verbs pronounced くる; but also overlap with the te-form of verbs with different dictionary-form pronunciations (such as 着る and 切る); and because it helps make a visual distinction that helps the reader with parsing.

Your comment that "you aren't helping towards that person - your aid isn't a form of motion" makes perfect sense, and sure enough, I checked online for examples of 手伝ってくる but really couldn't find any.  Makes sense!
